# For a lattice $L\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with base region $B$, how many points are in $L\cap nB$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory, integer-lattices

Take a lattice  $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and a convex region $B$ containing $0$ so that $\{B+\ell:\ell \in L\}$ partitions $\mathbb{R}^d$. Does $nB$ necessarily contain $n^d$ points in $L$? Convexity might not be needed.

Comment: This is immediate in some simple cases, like $L=\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $B=[-0.5,0.5)^d$ but I realized I could not prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $n\mathbf{I}_{d\times d}$ turns group $L$ into subgroup $nL\subset L$. 
Then by Corrollary 8.2.1 of *Lattice Coding of Signals and Networks* by Zamir, $|nB\cap L| = |\operatorname{det} n\mathbf{I}_{d\times d}|=n^d$

Proof is given by a somewhat involved discussion surrounding it.